# JNI crash outside the JVM in native code

Tags: c#, java, c++, java-native-interface, 32bit-64bit

I have a problem with a JNI based project. My java client calls a c# program via a c++ wrapper.

C# component was built in a 32bit environment and I'm working in a 64bit machine with a 64bit JVM. I have traced method calling sequence in all components, and what I have noticed is that error occurs when c++ wrapper calls the c# component.

I guess this happens because of 32bit - 64bit incompatibility. I found that this can be resolved with the use of DCOM, but I don't want to make this much complected.

the error I'm getting :-

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:143), pid=4884, tid=688 guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops) Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

Is it possible to resolve this without redoing the c# code?
thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to compile it in 64bit? if not you can use a 32bit jvm in ur java IDE

Comment: thanks for the advice, but both cases are not possible in my situation. I have to use 64bit JVM and 32bit dll file.

Comment: ok, i am currently working on native code too using 32bit dll and 32bit jvm on a 64bit machine, it work fine. however if i were to use 64bit jvm and 32bit dll it wont work. vice verses

Comment: Hi, in my situation, I'm using a 32bit dll in a 64bit jvm and as I have received a message when I enclosed my calling statement in a try-catch saying "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)". isn't it because of 32-64 incompatibility?